Prove G has a vertex of a degree 1, if G is a connected graph with n > 1 vertices and n - 1 edges.
Prove $G$ has a vertex of a degree $1$, if $G$ is a connected graph with $n > 1$ vertices and $n - 1$ edges.
It says to use the handshake lemma as a hint. and says what would happen if all the vertices had degree 2? but not sure how to prove this any further.
Proof: Let G be a connected graph with $n>1$ vertices and $n-1$ edges. By the handshake lemma, the sum of the degrees of all the vertices is twice the number of edges:
$$\sum_i\deg(v_i)=2(n-1)$$
...... Thus, we have shown that any connected graph with $n>1$ vertices and $n-1$ edges must have a vertex of degree $1$.

Using the method of proof by contradiction, if there are no points with a degree of 1, that is, each point has a degree of at least 2. So we have the number of edges is $\frac{\sum_{i}deg(v_{i})}{2} \geq \frac{2n}{2} = n$. So we came to the contradiction.

how did you get from 2(−1) to 2n/2? Thank you so much for helping!

You misunderstood. Here, I assumed that the degree of each point is greater than 1 (proof by contradiction).
